# Number theory and Dirichlet's principle problem

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Prove that there exists such a number, that can be divided by 2011 and ends with ...2010

Give me a hand, please. Unfortunately, i do not even know where to start.

Comment: Chinese Remainder Theorem

Comment: Consider the numbers $2010, 20102010, 201020102010, \cdots$. In the first 2012 numbers in the series there are two numbers with same remainder. See what you get when you subtract the two numbers with the same remainder.

Comment: Ok, will look into these. Thank a lot, all of you!

Comment: Can you solve the problem for smaller numbers? For instance *Prove that there exists such a number, that can be divided by $13$ and ends with $12$.* Please show the own effort... As it is, the (not explicitly stated) question is missing a lot of context... Adding context is important. (Else the question may be closed soon, there are good reasons to do it - as it stays there...)

Comment: Yes, thank for suggestion, but i solved it with some help of the people above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that was pretty obvious, thanks for pointing out, Asher2211. I knew that algorithm before, but wasn't able to see it here for some reason

His part of solution:

Consider the numbers $2010,20102010,201020102010,⋯$.
In the first $2012$ numbers in the series there are two numbers with same remainder.

My continuation:

If we subtract these two numbers were are left with
$20102010...2010000...$
Now we can divide it by $10^n$(depending on zeroes) and we are left with a number that can be divided by $2011$ and ends
with $2010$ . We can do it because $2011$ does not have the same multipliers(in fact, it is a prime number) as $10$.

Comment: Please use mathjax https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference for the mathematical objects involved in the answer.

Comment: Thank you for reminding!